# MS Excel Find & Match Duplicate Values & Return Duplicate Unique Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, match, unique

Using a MS Excel Formula, I have three Columns (i.e., Name, Phone, and Duplicate). I'm currently using a formula that finds matching duplicates based on two criterion (i.e., "NAME" and "DUPLICATE") and displays if duplicate is found to display in "Duplicate" column.

I would like an Excel Formula that if a duplicate record is found, to return the unique "PHONE" value, that corresponds and matches with the first instance of the duplicate "NAME" and "DUPLICATE" record and displays unique "Phone" number on the same row adjacent to duplicate record.

See Original Example Spreadsheet:

[image]

In the Sample output shown below, using MS Excel formula; instead of only identifying that a duplicate record has been found (i.e., Name & Duplicate); to display the unique value (Phone) identified as matching Name and Duplicate.

I would like to display the unique or second matching "Phone 2" as follows... Thanks

Sample Record Output Desired

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D2 as,

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)=1,IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("zzz",$A:$A)))/($A$2:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("zzz",$A:$A))=$A2),COLUMN(B:B))),""),"")
```

Fill down and right as necessary. Filling right will pick up the third, fourth duplocates if available.

Comment: Jeeped, your formula worked just like magic... thank you and thank you again for your assistance.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, are you able to explain two sections within your formula?  INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:, you used the term "Aggregate" followed with "(15,6, ROW" what are you actually telling the formula to do.  And lastly, you used the term "MATCH("zzz"," what are you telling the formula to do?

Comment: The **15** is the SMALL subfunction of [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF). COLUMN(B:B) = 2, filled right as 3, 4. The ROW supplies the matching row. MATCH("zzz".. makes you are only looking at the names. You should not use full column references with AGGREGATE.